# While loops generated via Scala Macros are not equal

Tags: scala, macros

While testing a macro (Scala 2.11.7) I ran into the following issue: generated while loops are not equal when compared with equalStructure. The following code snippet illustrates the issue:

```
  val actual = c.untypecheck(q"while (true) {}")
  val expected = c.untypecheck(q"while (true) {}")
  actual equalsStructure expected //is false
```

Is it by design or there is something which I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

Also the same for annotations:

```
> q"@enum object Test" equalsStructure(q"@enum object Test")
res1: Boolean = false
```

Which I assume is a bug, since this works as expected:

```
> q"object Test" equalsStructure(q"object Test")
res1: Boolean = true
```

I've raised a [issue](https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise/issues/80) on their github repo. Lets see what they say.